# Heroku not processing SBT dependencies correctly causing compile failure?

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt, playframework-2.1

I have a poker implementation in a project called engine. Inside my projects/build.scala file, the project definition:

```
lazy val engine = Project(id = "engine", base = file("engine"))
    .settings(...)
```

The Scala sources inside the engine directory are declared under **bitpoker.engine**

Then I have the Play  2.1 frontend defined as:

```
lazy val webClient = play.Project("web-client", path = file("BitPoker"))
      .settings(...)
    .dependsOn(engine)
```

The Scala sources inside the BitPoker (web-client) directory reference objects from bitpoker.engine.

I have a top level project:

```
lazy val bitPoker = Project(id = "bit-poker", base = file("."))
    .settings(...)
    .dependsOn(webClient).aggregate(webClient)
```

Running the command "sbt clean compile stage" works locally but when I push to heroku using "git push heroku master" I get:

```
[info] Compiling 59 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /tmp/build_15alo7gjz26s2/BitPoker/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /tmp/build_15alo7gjz26s2/BitPoker/app/models/game/GameSearcher.scala:4: object engine is not a member of package bitpoker
```

among many other "not found" errors that occur whenever I reference something in bitpoker.engine.

Is Heroku ignoring my dependencies or is something else happening?

I'm using Play 2.1-RC1, Scala 2.1.10, and SBT 0.12.1

Comment: Did you try unsing the sbt console directly on Heroku ? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala#console

Comment: @nico_ekito I did not know this was a possibility, I'll try it now

Comment: @nico_ekito I got: Running `sbt console` attached to terminal... up, run.1523
bash: sbt: command not found

Comment: Just tried it, and it works for me. What versions of sbt, play and scala are you using ?

Comment: I just added those details to the question. But it shouldn't matter right? It seems like sbt is not installed on Heroku's side.

Comment: If it weren't installed on Heroku, you'd never be able to compile and get the error you mentioned ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23653/discussion-between-mark-and-nico-ekito)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The engine project was declared to live at `path = file("engine")` whereas the actual code lived at `Engine` with a captial "E". This compiles on Windows 7 64 bit, but crashed on Heroku. The fix was changing the path declaration for the engine project to: `path = file("Engine")`